# React - comunication between components (for beginners)

Tags: reactjs

I am realatively new in React JS. Few weeks ago I created To Do List app in JS, jQuery and now I am going to rebuilt it using React, just for change my point of view and practice React.

I have few components (siblings) in different files and one parent component - App, components:

App:
- Navigation
- Task List
- Add Task
- Footer

**How can my navigation component communicate with task list component?** 
To be more specific I want to have something like **global variable** selectedDay and use it in all components. 
When user choose in Navigation component single day, for example Sunday , I want to save "sunday" in this variable and later use it in Task List (this is of course sample example of data). My question is **how to store data in first component and use it in another one**?

Should I use state for this kind of purposes? I was thinking about set initial state in parent (App) component -> selectedDay : "monday"   /default/ and later update it by Navigation component and use in Task List component. Could you help me, please? I will be gratefull!

Comment: You should read https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions for this.

1- Use a library that handles a global state, like Redux (as FurkanO said). That way, your "big components" (aka containers) are connected to the global state of your application, and update it with actions.
Actions are some kind of events with a type, and sometimes a payload, that will be intercepted by a reducer and trigger a state update.

2- Use the state of the lowest common parent of the components you want to see interracting.

Basic Example for 2- : Parent Component contains Navigation & TaskList.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedDay: defaultDay,
  }

  setDay = (selectedDay) => {
    this.setState({ selectedDay });
  }

  render () {
    const { selectedDay } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation setDay={this.setDay} />
        <TaskList selectedDay={selectedDay} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then you just use this setDay function in your Navigation component to set the state in the Parent Component. That way, your TaskList will receive the new value via its props.
This method has its limits (it really doesn't scale well in my opinion).

Hope that helped. Please tell me if this isn't clear for you.

Comment: Glad it could help. Don't hesitate tu accept the answer (or FurkanO's, for that matter) if that fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is redux. It provides you a global state tree which is an object, a way to manipulate it and most importantly whenever your state tree changes rerenders your components. So that your components are always up-to-date with updated state tree.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about it, I read few articles and tutorials. But I thought that maybe it will be better to do it first in pure React just to understand it and later again rebuilt it using Redux. I will try @felix-kling solution (now I have some problems with it ;) and later I will read more about Redux and try it..